# Remove draggable from clone after being dropped, but retain event bindings?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, draggable, droppable

I've got a jQuery `draggable` concept I'm having trouble with. Here is the example:

http://jsfiddle.net/3CtfD/3/

Basically, I've got a draggable element - the little red box. You can click and drag it into the table on the right, and when you drop it into a table cell it will fill up that cell. This part works fine.

Here's where I am stumped:

1. I need `helper: "clone"` in the `draggable` initialization so that the click event binding is passed along to the clone. You can see this if you remove `true` from `clone(true)` in `DroppedOnGrid`, you will no longer get the `alert` when clicking on a red box that has been dropped onto the grid. **This part works fine.**
2. Once a red box has been dropped onto the grid, and it has expanded to fill the cell, I want to remove the `draggable` functionality from that clone so it cannot be dragged again. You'll notice how once you drop a red box onto the grid and then try and drag that clone you're still actually grabbing the little red box on the left.

If I remove `true` from `clone(true)`, it works as expected but I lose my click event binding on the clone.

I've tried updating the `DroppedOnGrid` function to use:

```
ui.draggable.clone(true).css({ height: "100%", width: "100%"}).appendTo($(this)).draggable("destroy");
```

Which results in:

> Cannot read property 'options' of undefined

I've also tried simply removing the `ui-draggable` class:

```
ui.draggable.clone(true).css({ height: "100%", width: "100%"}).appendTo($(this)).removeClass("ui-draggable");
```

But this had no effect. Lastly, I've tried *disabling* draggable:

```
ui.draggable.clone(true).css({ height: "100%", width: "100%"}).appendTo($(this)).draggable("disable");
```

But this results in the little red box on the left also becoming disabled.

**Does anyone know how I can achieve both passing the click event through to the clone, but disabling `draggable` once it has been placed on to the grid?**

Comment: How about this? http://jsfiddle.net/Rd83F/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is better not to `clone(true)` as draggable widget might have events attached to item being dragged. Instead you can just clone the element and attach your event to the parent container.

```
$("#target, #origin").on("click", ".box", function () {
    alert('clicked');
});
```

and

```
 ui.draggable.clone().css({
        height: "100%",
        width: "100%"
 }).appendTo($(this));
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Rd83F/)**